# Awesome WM: Reverse mouse buttons

Tags: awesome-wm

I have a pretty standard installation of the Awesome Window Manager on Arch. I am left-handed and wish to reverse the order of the mouse buttons so that the primary mouse button is the right mouse button and the left is secondary. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure custom mouse events for panel, menu and other awesome stuff in rc file, but it will not affect your applications. To make global reverse for all system try adding this to your `.xinitrc`:

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1"
```